# Select query in sqlite ROOM databse taking time more than 30 secoond

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

```
SELECT * FROM ReferenceIdentifier WHERE sValue = :sValue and status='ACTIVE
```

this simple select query taking too mush time

below is my code

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ReferenceIdentifier WHERE sValue = :sValue and status='ACTIVE'")

fun getAllReferenceIdentifierBySValue(sValue: String): List<ReferenceIdentifier>

    appExecutors.diskIO().execute {
                var data = referenceIdentifierDao.getAllReferenceIdentifierBySValue(sValue)
                appExecutors.mainThread().execute {
                    if (data.isNotEmpty()) {
                    result.value = Resource.success(data)
                } else {
                    result.value = Resource.error("", null)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204199/discussion-on-question-by-ashim-saini-select-query-in-sqlite-room-databse-taking).